# Were the Xindi in Enterprise and the Xendi in The Next Generation the same species?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-enterprise, xindi

TNG "The Battle":

> Captain's log, stardate 41723.9. In response to a Starfleet order we
>   are in the **Xendi** Sabu star system, having rendezvoused with a
>   Ferengi vessel which has requested a meeting. Although we arrived here
>   and made appropriate signals to the Ferengi three days ago, they have
>   so far responded only with the message, stand by Enterprise

later:

> DATA: Starfleet has responded to our request, sir. A tug will
>   rendezvous with us and tow the Stargazer back to **Xendi** Starbase
>   Nine

I'm not going to quote the Xindi since they take up two seasons of "Enterprise".

Are they the same species?

Answer (score 2):

## It seems not

There are in fact, according to Memory Alpha and Beta at least, is no evidence to support the claim that there are such a species as the Xendi at all!

We do have:

- The [Xendi Kabu system](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Xendi_Kabu_system), referenced in *Bloodlines*
- The [Xendi Sabu](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Xendi_Sabu_system) system, referenced in *The Battle*
- [Xendi Starbase 9](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Xendi_Starbase_9) which is in close proximity to the Xendi Sabu system.

The source of those names,  however, is not provided either on Memory Alpha *or* Beta!

It is also important to note that:

> According to Star Trek: The Next Generation Companion (2nd ed., p.
>   294), **the Xendi Kabu system from "Bloodlines" was intended to be the
>   same system [as the Xendi Sabu system]**; the name was mistakenly changed in a late draft of that
>   episodes script.

([Source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Xendi_Sabu_system))

So, there shouldn't even be two systems with the name 'Xendi' anyway!

Comment: I'm not sure you can give a blanket "no" without providing any better justification than a wiki article.

Comment: So what is the "Xendi" in "Xendi Kabu system" referring to?

Comment: @JMFB I would suspect it is just like many other systems was a name made up, but I don't have any evidence for that

Comment: @Richard I would love to be able to find any other evidence, but I've done some research and this was the best I could find!  I've adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: @N_Soong - Much better. I do agree that they're almost certainly unrelated.

Comment: @Richard Glad that it's better now :D